# wget OpenSSL: error:140770FC:SSL on same server only

Tags: ssl, wget

I am trying to wget a https address on my own server (example.com):

```
wget https://www.example.com/abc
```

And get the following error:

```
--2016-11-25 12:11:16--  https://www.example.com/abc
Resolving www.example.com (www.example.com)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to www.example.com (www.example.com)|127.0.0.1|:443... connected.
OpenSSL: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

Doing the same request to example.com from another server (example2.com) works fine.

I am using a letsencrypt certificate on example.com

Comment: Why is www.example.com resolving to 127.0.0.1 (localhost)? What if you `wget https://<ip-of-host>/abc`? Is your http server listening on 127.0.0.1:443 (`netstat -nap`)?

Comment: wget of my own ip: ERROR: certificate common name 'example.com' doesn't match requested host name 'XX.XX.XX.XX'. The www.example.com is in the /etc/hosts file. Is that the problem?

Comment: Your /etc/hosts file should resolve `www.example.com` to the network address your server is listening on and `localhost` to 127.0.0.1. Again, try `netstat -nap | grep 443`.

Comment: Right. That was it. I just changed the /etc/hosts file.! Thanks!